# JSON into Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Currently I have a variable called "data" that I assign static JSON data, then push the values to arrays using three variables named rev_date, rev_area & rev_cases, using the following Javascript code;

```
data = [{
  "date": "2020-10-17",
  "areaName": "Devon",
  "newCasesByPublishDate": "108"
}, {
  "date": "2020-10-16",
  "areaName": "Devon",
  "newCasesByPublishDate": "76"
}];

let rev_date = [];
let rev_area = [];
let rev_cases = [];

data.map((item) => {
    rev_date.push(item.date);
    rev_area.push(item.areaName);
    rev_cases.push(item.newCasesByPublishDate);
  });
```

My question is, there is an api that returns the same data in JSON format, using the following URL - [https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=utla;areaName=devon&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate"}](https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=utla;areaName=devon&structure=%7B%22date%22:%22date%22,%22areaName%22:%22areaName%22,%22newCasesByPublishDate%22:%22newCasesByPublishDate%22%7D)

Is there an easy way using ajax or something else to replace my static "data" variable holding the JSON data, to pull the data dynamically from the URL above?

Comment: *"Currently I have a variable called "data" that I assign static JSON data"* No, you assign it static **data** (specifically, an array of objects). JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Read this along with the other linked posts: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/4642212).